# cURL как получить ref id после post запроса и редиректов

Tags: php, curl, ref

Создал два сайта, один обработчик, второй отправляет ему post запрос с именем домена, первый - второму возвращает код домена (сайта), т.е. на втором сайте после выполнения post запроса открывается сайт который и был в post запросе к первому домену.

Можно как-то от первого домена (скрипта) получить куку на втором домене, чтобы открытие сайта по реферальной ссылке на втором домене считалось за реферальный переход?

На первом сайте я умею сохранять куку в файл, думал этого достаточно, стал проверять статистику - реферальных переходов нет

Помогите разобраться с куками, пожалуйста.

Вот часть основного кода (обработчик)

```
<?php 

$url = $_POST["url"];


// инициализация сеанса 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// используем User Agent браузера
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);

// установка URL и других необходимых параметров 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

// Имитируем классический браузер и сохраняем COOKIES
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

//TRUE для принудительного использования нового соединения вместо закэшированного.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false); 

// в случае необходимости, следовать по перенаправлени¤м
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// устанавливаем максимальное время конекта 5 секунд
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

// Опция указывает, что результат будет записан в переменную
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// загрузка страницы и выдача её браузеру 
$page_source = curl_exec($ch);

// Получаю итоговый url после всех редиректов 
$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);


echo $page_source;

//print_r (curl_getinfo($ch));

// завершение сеанса и освобождение ресурсов 
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

как этим кодом вернуть куку на другой сайт - сайт который отправляет данному скрипту url?

Нашел инструкцию но не понял ее http://www.php.su/forum/topic.php?forum=74&topic=1893

А вот код самого сайта (приемник), куда и должна вернуться кука, данный сайт отправляет post запрос первому скрипту

```
<?php 
// URL скрипта обработчика
$login_url = 'http://сайт.ru/inc.php';

// параметры для отправки запроса
$post_data = array(
'url' => 'http://reflink.ru/id555',

'cookielength' => '-1',
'hash_passwrd' => ''
);

// создание объекта curl
$ch = curl_init();

// используем User Agent браузера
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);

// задаем URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

// указываем что это POST запрос
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

// задаем параметры запроса
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

// указываем, чтобы нам вернулось содержимое после запроса
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');


// выполняем запрос
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);

echo $postResult;

?>
```

30,06 Проблема все еще актуальна, пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Да, передать cookies можно, но лучше передавать их не в файле cookie.txt (тем более, если вам требуется только один ref_id), а через параметры POST-запроса. Выставляйте cookies:

```
setcookie('ref_id', $ref_id, strtotime('+1 year'), '', '');
```

Затем считываете их в следующем запросе и передаете на второй домен в виде списка параметров.

P.S. И лучше используется для cURL Options массивы, а не задание параметров построчно (лучше curl_setopt_array вместо curl_setopt). Так код короче и становится более читабельным.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61653/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-maslennikov-curl---ref-id--post-).